# Getting rid of vertical space in a cell

Tags: tables

**EDIT\ANSWER:** I got the look I wanted by creating two tables, one with a mix of p and m columns for the headers and one with all p columns, then stacking them one on top of another. There was a bit of white space in between that I got rid of by using `\vspace{-2pt}`.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:** I am trying to create a template for the school report using LaTex. This is the code so far. I like the position of text in the first row, but I would like less vertical padding for text in all subsequent rows. I am just a beginner in LaTex and I apologize if the question is too obvious.

[image: report_format_draft]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm]   {geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{colori}{RGB}{249,193,158}
\definecolor{colorii}{RGB}{158,214,149}
\newcommand\skilllevel[1]{%%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \Val in {1,2,3,4,5}
{
    \node[draw,fill=white,inner ysep=4pt] 
    at ([yshift=10*\Val]0,\Val pt) {};
}
\foreach \Val in {1,...,#1}
{
    \node[draw,fill=colorii,inner ysep=4pt] 
    at ([yshift=10*\Val]0,\Val pt) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|p{5.1cm}|m{0.2cm}|m{0.2cm}|m{0.2cm}|p{5.2cm}|c|}
    %\hline \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex} %
    \hline \textbf{Subject} & \vspace{-19pt}\begin{center}
        \textbf{Knowledge and Skills}
    \end{center} & \rotatebox[origin=rB]{90}{Homework} & \rotatebox[origin=rB]{90}{Attitude} & \rotatebox[origin=rB]{90}{ Participation} & \vspace{-19pt}\begin{center}\textbf{Teacher Comments}\end{center} & \textbf{Grade} \\ 
    \hline \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex} \emph{Biology} & \lipsum[66] & \vspace{12pt}\skilllevel{2} & \vspace{12pt}\skilllevel{3} & \vspace{12pt}\skilllevel{4} & \lipsum[75] & \textbf{Exceptional} \\ 
    \hline \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex} \emph{Chemistry}  &  \lipsum[66] & \vspace{12pt}\skilllevel{2} & \vspace{12pt}\skilllevel{4} & \vspace{12pt}\skilllevel{5} & \lipsum[75] & \textbf{Very Good} \\ 
    \hline \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex} \emph{English} & \lipsum[75] & \vspace{12pt}\skilllevel{2}  & \vspace{12pt}\skilllevel{5}  & \vspace{12pt}\skilllevel{1} & \lipsum[66] & \textbf{Good} \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: With other words: the green squares should be shifted more downwards and at the bottom of the cell the space should be removed?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it.

Comment: On a different note, here is a more compact version of your `tikz` code (just change the colors): `\begin{tikzpicture}  \foreach \Val in {0,...,4}{ \ifnum#1>\Val\relax\def\mycolor{black}\else\def\mycolor{none}\fi \node[draw,fill=\mycolor,inner ysep=4pt] at ([yshift=10*\Val]0,0 pt) {};} \end{tikzpicture}}`

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You have used a mixture of `m` and `p` columns, which is usually a mistake, use all `p` or all `m`

As shown by the red line, the baseline of the top row of a `p` column is aligned with the vertical centre of `m`.

---

[image]

Using `m` and lots of dubious `\vspace` removed:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm]   {geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{colori}{RGB}{249,193,158}
\definecolor{colorii}{RGB}{158,214,149}
\newcommand\skilllevel[1]{%%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \Val in {1,2,3,4,5}
{
    \node[draw,fill=white,inner ysep=4pt] 
    at ([yshift=10*\Val]0,\Val pt) {};
}
\foreach \Val in {1,...,#1}
{
    \node[draw,fill=colorii,inner ysep=4pt] 
    at ([yshift=10*\Val]0,\Val pt) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|m{5.1cm}|l|l|l|m{5.2cm}|c|}
    %\hline \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex} %
    \hline \textbf{Subject} & \centering
        \textbf{Knowledge and Skills}
    & \rotatebox[origin=rB]{90}{Homework} & \rotatebox[origin=rB]{90}{Attitude} & \rotatebox[origin=rB]{90}{ Participation} & \centering \textbf{Teacher Comments} & \textbf{Grade} \\ 
    \hline \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex} \emph{Biology} & \lipsum[66] & \skilllevel{2} & \skilllevel{3} & \skilllevel{4} & \lipsum[75] & \textbf{Exceptional} \\ 
    \hline \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex} \emph{Chemistry}  &  \lipsum[66] & \skilllevel{2} & \skilllevel{4} & \skilllevel{5} & \lipsum[75] & \textbf{Very Good} \\ 
    \hline \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex} \emph{English} & \lipsum[75] & \skilllevel{2}  &\skilllevel{5}  & \skilllevel{1} & \lipsum[66] & \textbf{Good} \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: less space, but, ugh!, the first line of text is mashed up against the rule above it.  and i wonder why you didn't just align the tops of the squares with the top line of text.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes well I considered doing something about the space after the lines but stuck to answering the question:-) `\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}` probably fixes that, I guessed the OP wanted them centred, could be wrong of course.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is, if I do it that way, the headers are all top aligned vertically. I would like to keep the headers centered vertically, but text in the columns below them top aligned. There should also be less empty space after the text in the cell. Is there an equivalent of the  `\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}` to fine-tune the amount of white space after the text?